# Programming method

Tags: vb.net

When I am programming in VB.net, I usually use a normal methodology (I think).

When I have a form, and some buttons placed on it, and some functions under this buttons, I implement the functionality of this buttons in the moment the button is pressed, for example:

- I press a button, inside the button I use nested If..else structure to do something in order of a given condition. When the condition is true, I obtain a specific result.

I have heard (and I am not able to find information) about another methodology, where this if..else structure is not done each time you press the button, but the structure only executes one time, and not need to pass throught the if..else structure more times. Is like the program knows the solution without doing this structure all the times the button is pressed. Only needs to do it the first one.

I don't know if someone understand my question, but if someone knows about what I am talking and could give me some useful information, I would be very grateful!
i don't even know if this methodology exists, but I heard about it and I would like to investigate..

I am investigating about the performance of the programs I am creating..

Comment: This is too vague.  Of course if you want something to happen when a button is clicked you need code in the click event handler.  It might just be one line to call something else, but there is code there.  Thats not a methodology.  nor are `If`'s.  You might want to clarify what you are really asking

Comment: Can you provide us the related code to help clarify what you're asking?

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're looking for the Select..Case..End Select.. But to be honest - If you dont have a specific fault and error with your code, this question belongs in Code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a member-level variable to detect if the button click handler code has been executed.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private isInitialized As Boolean

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Do some stuff if this is the first time the button was clicked.
        If Not isInitialized Then

            'do some stuff...

            isInitialized = True
        End If
        'Do some other stuff each time the button is pressed.

        'do some stuff...

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

Finally I understood how the methodology I've heard works.

It is quite simple, but my question was not well made, so now I know that my answer is too vague.

I didn't know, because of my few experience programming controls, that I can made my own control which I can use in my forms. With this, I can paint this control in the way I want. I am going to put an example that answer the problem I had:

A control that will be a clock, and this clock can be analogic or digital. Before I knew this, I had a button named 'Change Clock' which change the appareance of the clock between analogic and digital. And when I press that button, in the click event of the button, I start to paint the clock, either is analogic or digital.

Now I know that programming controls, I am able to made a control by creating a UserControl in my project, and inside the code of this new control I can use the paint event to paint the clock in order of a property. Something like this:

```
Private Sub AnalogClock_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Select Case m_contenido
        Case formatoReloj.analogico
            'Paint analogic clock
        Case formatoReloj.digital
            'Paint digital clock
    End Select
End Sub
```

and when I use this control in my form, I only need to change the property of the clock and not to paint everything each time I want to change it. That means that is already painted in the code of the control and I have not to use code in my form to do it..

I hope you understand now what I wanted..

Comment: While this approach will work, a *better* way to do it would be to abstract the drawing code in to a "clock renderer", some a class that knows how to draw each type of clock, and only does the drawing.  I would create an `IClockRenderer` interface with a `Draw` method that takes the time, and a `Graphics` target argument.  Then I would create `DigitalClock` and `AnalogClock`  classes that implement that interface.  Your user control can have an `IClockRenderer` property that you set to that appropriate type of `IClockRenderer`.  The `Paint` of your control just calls the interface...

Comment: ...This keeps the code all nice any contained, so you are not mixing up logic for the different kind of clocks.  It would also allow you to extend it to all kinds of different clock faces. You could have 5 different styles of analog clock face, that only differ based on the type of `IClockRenderer` that they have.

Comment: Amazing way to do it! Now I am going to start learning about interfaces. Sorry for my unexperience, but could you give me a very simple example of how to do this with interfaces? Now I am going to start with a real/fake environment using interfaces, and maybe I can learn with this example, My colleague is programming the real environment, and I have to program the fake environment to work this the program while I wait for the real one. I have to create an interface that calls the fakes one while the real one is not ready.. Maybe you know about how to do this? Thanks a lot @BradleyUffner!

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes and I'll have something really simple for you to follow.

Comment: I've created a partial example for you on BitBucket. https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/clockexample/src